# Django orm: How to annotate a model with a related relation traversing multiple table

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have this structure

```
class lvlOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class lvlTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(lvlOne, related_name="children")


class lvlThree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(lvlTwo)
```

is there way to annotate instances of lvlOne with a Related Manger of lvlThree, am thinking something like this

```
obj = lvlOne.objects.annotate(grandchildren = .... ).get()

obj.children.all() # all related lvlTwo instances as expected from setting related_name 
obj.grandchildren.all() # all related lvlThree instances
```

Couple things i tried

- Using postgres specific [ArrayAGG](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) I managed to get a similar result, but its still a list of id (or name etc) Not the actual objects.
- Using [Prefetch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) and [FilteredRelation()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) seems to apply on immedate relation only, every time the lookup traverse to another Model, the prefetch does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I can share some points from my experience.

- doing `Subquery` inside `annotate` is helpful. It is worth noticing that `annotate` requires the return to be a single value, not a list of values or an object
- What about starting with `lvlThree` and annotating related `lvlOne`?

Comment: ty for your response. There no  issue starting with lvlThree and annotating related lvlOne. Obviously there is many ways, you can collect the data/information you need, in a similar context. I was wondering if what i suggested is possible with queryset.